Help modeling specific constraint
I have the following variables and I am trying to formulate a suitable constraint. I have the binary variables $a_{ij}$ and $b_{ij}$ and now I want to encode $c_{ij}$ (also binary). $c_{ij}$ should take the value of 1 if both of the following conditions are fulfilled at the same time.
\begin{align}
a_{ij}&=1 \tag1 \\
\sum_{k=1}^j b_{ik}&=0 \tag2
\end{align}
It should be valid for all $i$ and $j$ and work best without parameterization of e.g. a large constant.

typo in condition 2 ? is it $\sum b_{ij} = 0$? over which index ?

The solution depends on more than what you've written. You need to specify what the objective is, because the objective sense dictates which simplifications you can get away with.

Also, as kuifje says, the dimensions of the second constraint don't make any sense. If you're summing over one dimension in $a$, you're left with $i$ expressions. How do you compare those to $i,j$ matrix elements of $c$?

You want to enforce the logical implication $$\left(a_{ij} \land \bigwedge_{k=1}^j \lnot b_{ik} \right) \implies c_{ij}.$$
Rewriting in conjunctive normal form automatically leads to linear constraints:
$$
\lnot\left(a_{ij} \land \bigwedge_{k=1}^j \lnot b_{ik} \right) \lor c_{ij} \\
\lnot a_{ij} \lor \bigvee_{k=1}^j b_{ik} \lor c_{ij} \\
(1-a_{ij}) + \sum_{k=1}^j b_{ik} + c_{ij} \ge 1
$$

To enforce the converse
$$c_{ij} \implies \left(a_{ij} \land \bigwedge_{k=1}^j \lnot b_{ik} \right),$$
follow the same approach:
$$
\lnot c_{ij} \lor \left(a_{ij} \land \bigwedge_{k=1}^j \lnot b_{ik} \right) \\
\left(\lnot c_{ij} \lor a_{ij}\right) \land \left(\lnot c_{ij} \lor \bigwedge_{k=1}^j \lnot b_{ik} \right) \\
\left(\lnot c_{ij} \lor a_{ij}\right) \land \bigwedge_{k=1}^j \left(\lnot c_{ij} \lor \lnot b_{ik} \right) \\
\left((1-c_{ij}) + a_{ij}\ge 1\right) \land \bigwedge_{k=1}^j \left((1- c_{ij}) + (1-b_{ik}) \ge 1 \right)
$$
That is,
\begin{align}
c_{ij} &\le a_{ij} &&\text{for all $i$ and $j$} \\
b_{ik} + c_{ij} &\le 1 &&\text{for all $i$ and $j$ and $k\in\{1,\dots,j\}$}
\end{align}

Thank you very much. Thats exactly what i was looking for. I still have a question however. Right now, this constraint set a LB for $c_{ij}$. If this LB is equal to one, then $c_{ij}$ takes on the value of one, however in the other cases, f.e. if $a_{ij}=1$ and $\sum_{k=1}^{j}b_{ik}=3$, this yields $c_{ij}\ge -2 $ or in the binary case $c_{ij}\ge 0$. But couldnt it be the case, that solver assigns $c_{ij}=1$ nonetheless. How can i force a 0 in any other case?

Thanks. Assuming the sum not from 1 till $j$, but from $j-5$ till $j-1$. Would the constraints then look like this?
$b_{ik} + c_{ij} \le 1 & \forall i,j, k\in {j-5,...,j-1}$ and $(1-a_{ij}) + \sum_{k=j-5}^{j-1} b_{ik} + c_{ij} \ge 1 \forall i,j$

@Uniewr Yes, that is correct.

$a_{i,j} \le c_{i,j} + \sum_{k}^{j} b_{i,k}$
$c_{i,j} +b_{i,k }\le a_{i,j} + 1 \ \ \forall k =\{1,...j\}$

Your first constraint is a rewrite of mine.  Your second constraint mistakenly allows $c_{ij}=1,b_{ik}=0,a_{ij}=0$.
